# Как добавить ссылку на скачивание файла JS?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить ссылку на скачивание pdf-файла. Атрибут "downoload" к сожалению не поддерживается. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать через JS или PHP?

Comment: Что значит не поддерживается?

Comment: Да, извиняюсь за неточность. Не поддерживается на мобильной версии.

Comment: На мобильной версии чего?

Comment: На мобильной версии браузера.

Comment: Какого браузера?

Comment: Safari  и Chrome

Comment: Chrome поддерживает

Comment: А вообще отправляйте с файлом HTTP-заголовок [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Content-Disposition), его вроде поддерживают все, в том числе Safari